# How to fix error: [!] Unable to find a specification for `My Own Cocoapods repo`?

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I made cocoa pod repository with 'SayHello2' name successfully.
Like this:
[image]

And update my GitHub : [SayHello2 Github Address](https://github.com/reza-khalafi/SayHello2)

I think everything is correct. but when search my project in cocoapods.org  not found it.  and when try to add this pod to Xcode project get this error:
[image]

and this is my spec file:

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint SayHello2.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'SayHello2'
s.version          = '0.1.0'
s.summary          = 'And just SayHello2.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!


s.description      = "This is just a testing a git with cocoapods - SayHello2."


s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/reza-khalafi/SayHello2'
# s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'reza-khalafi' => 'r.khalafi65@gmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/reza-khalafi/SayHello2.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
# s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

s.source_files = 'SayHello2/Classes/**/*'

# s.resource_bundles = {
#   'SayHello2' => ['SayHello2/Assets/*.png']
# }

# s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
# s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
# s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Check the attached image.

[image]

Comment: I uninstalled cocoapods completely and reinstall again. Tnx

Comment: But i think take a time for release by cocoapods.